# In Primefaces, how to get a widget by widget type in javascript

Tags: javascript, primefaces, widget

In Primefaces, I want to get a list of Widget which is "InputSwitch" or something else. How could I do that.

In Primefaces, I see there a list of Widgets which is in the page by code:

```
PrimeFaces.widgets
```

Or get widget by id

```
PrimeFaces.getWidgetById("someId");
```

But I do not know how to get a list of widget by widget Type sample as `PrimeFaces.widget.InputSwitch`

Answer (score 1):

In PrimeFaces, they support jQuery, and to get a jQuery object by simply:

```
PrimeFaces.widgets["someWidgetVar"].getJQ()
```

Simple way to archive getting a list of InputSwitch is

```
for (item in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
    widget =  PrimeFaces.widgets[item];
    if (widget.getJQ().hasClass('ui-inputswitch')) {
        list.push(widget);
    }
}
```

With `'ui-inputswitch'` is the CSS class of PrimeFaces component.

Comment: `if (widget instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.InputSwitch) {list.push(widget);}` does work too. Here you do not rely on the css but actual widget type so it is in my (not so) humble opinion the better choice